# Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 not booting to desktop after upgrade

Tags: boot, 22.04, ubuntu-studio

I upgraded to Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 from 22.04 a couple of days ago. Since then the system does not want to boot into the graphical desktop on its own anymore.

When I boot normally, it shows the Ubuntu Studio splash screen briefly, then goes back to the terminal which shows only one message related to mtd which I think is unrelated to the problem, and after a few seconds the HDD stops working and it just sits there. I can go to a login terminal with Ctrl-Alt-F1, login and then `startx` and it will boot to desktop normally.

When I boot in recovery mode, and then immediately "Resume normal boot" after enabling networking, it will boot fine into the desktop as well.

With earlier kernels it is the same.

Did `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and all is up-to-date.

Looked through various log files, and nothing suspicious seems to stand out.

My system:

- AMD Ryzen 5 1600
- NVidia GTX1050Ti (NVidia driver 515)

What is also weird, but not sure if related, is that the NVidia X Server Settings app that is installed with the driver is almost empty, and does not contain all the options I am used to from my production system running on the same PC.

Everything worked fine before the update.

What could be the problem?

EDIT: Before doing `startx` from the command line, there is no Xorg.log created, so it appears the boot procedure does not even try to start an X server.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the NVIDIA driver is being loaded too late (X11 starting before the driver is ready).

You may workaround this by adding the NVIDIA driver to initrd for Early KMS:

```bash
echo "nvidia" | sudo tee --append /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
echo "nvidia_modeset" | sudo tee --append /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
echo "nvidia_uvm" | sudo tee --append /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
echo "nvidia_drm" | sudo tee --append /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

If done properly then:

```bash
lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r) | grep nvidia
```

should return something (that is related to GPU, not the ethernet controller nor `i2c-nvidia-gpu.ko`)

Then restart. If this breaks your machine (it shouldn't...), remove the lines added to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and run `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` again.

SDDM [ran into this issue](https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/1316) and fixed it by retrying multiple times (more [discussion](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=260525)).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! While it does sound like that is the problem, it turns out that it was just the wrong kernel being loaded that caused the problem. A simple `update-grub` fixed it. So while your steps are not actually the solution, and not necessary in my case, they helped me find the true root cause.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that, in my case, it was just the wrong kernel being loaded after the update that caused the problem.

I noticed that both `/boot/initrd.img` and `/boot/vmlinuz` were pointing to the latest 5.15.0-46-lowlatency kernel, but doing `uname -r` revealed that actually still the previous 5.15.0-27-lowlatency kernel was being loaded. The grub menu did not contain the 5.15.0-46 kernels either.

Doing a simple `sudo update-grub` and rebooting fixed the issue, including the missing entries in NVidia X Server Settings. It appears that X was using the nouveau driver when started manually.

EDIT: I found out that in my case, the cause of the problem was that I had two EFI System Partitions on two different disks running, but only one of them was used during booting. So when the 22.04 system updated the kernel, it did not update the bootloader that was actually used for booting. I had to run `update-grub` from the other Ubuntu I had running in parallel so I could boot correctly into the 22.04 system.